# Trying to push a dynamic textarea to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, textarea

I'm almost there and can taste it, but I cant get this last little part over to getpost.php. Basically I have dynamic textareas where users can add steps. Say if they add 5 steps, im needing those steps added to mysql database via PHP. I'm not sure of the php I need in order to do this. Any help I would greatly appreciate!

here is my post.php with the steps:

```
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

var counter = 2;

$("#addButton").click(function () {

if(counter>10){
        alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
        return false;
}   

var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<p><label>Step #'+ counter + ' : </label><br>' +
      '<textarea rows="10" cols="150" type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
      '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


counter++;
 });

 $("#removeButton").click(function () {
if(counter==1){
      alert("No more steps to remove");
      return false;
   }   

counter--;

    $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

 });

 $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

var msg = '';
for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
  msg += "\n Step #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
}
      alert(msg);
 });




});
</script>

</head>

<body>
Add new step below:<p>

<form action="getpost.php" method="post">
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
<div id="TextBoxDiv1">
    <label>Step #1 : </label><br />
    <textarea rows="10" cols="150" type='textbox' id='textbox1'></textarea>
</div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Add Step' id='addButton'>
<input type='button' value='Remove Step' id='removeButton'>
<input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'>
<input type="submit" />
</form>


</body>
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/pdo or http://www.php.net/mysqli is the first step

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery's clone method for achieve dynamical creation of textboxes.
try this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js">   </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var counterb = 1;
$("#addathletehistory").click(function(){
if(counterb>6){
        alert("Maximum 5 textarea allow");
        return false;
}   
$("#sport_history").clone().attr({"id":"sport_history"+counterb, "name":"sport_history"+counterb}).add("<br/>").appendTo("#stablehistory");
counterb++;
  });
});
```

this jquery code create 5 text areas by clicking on a button "add more" .note that,  the id and name of each new textarea is changed as i add counter's value to it.
hope it help.
happy coding!